# Working with context-menu and port

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I read at [working with content scripts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/dev-guide/addon-development/web-content.html) that one can use port with context-menu, but the following code gives me an error: cm.port is undefined. The same code works with `require("panel")` when I emit an event, but not with context menu. What am doing wrong?

This is main.js

```
const data = require('self').data;
var cm = require("context-menu").Item({
label: "asdasd",
  contentScriptFile: data.url("panel.js")
});

cm.port.emit("myEvent", "panel is showing");
```

this panel.js

```
console.log("entering the panel.js file...");
self.on("click", function(node,data) {
self.port.emit("asd");
});

self.port.on("myEvent", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: The error message doesn't match your code. Do you mean "cm.port is undefined"?

Comment: FTR, one can communicate with the page by associating the cm to a pageMod as per http://stackoverflow.com/a/11768820/271577 (for a workaround to https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=824348 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To quote [the documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/using-port.html):

> The panel and page-worker objects integrate the worker API directly. So to receive events from a content script associated with a panel you use panel.port.on()

What you are using is neither `panel` nor `page-worker` but `context-menu`. And the `context-menu` package doesn't allow bi-directional communication with the content script. Again, if you look at [the documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.12/modules/sdk/context-menu.html): you can only receive messages sent by the content script but not send messages to it. Instead, the messages `context` and `click` are sent to the content script automatically in appropriate situations.

Comment: What was not obvious to those of us who don't read all the docs first is that the solution is to use `postMessage()` from the content script and onMessage within the context menu item (`cm`).

Comment: @iND: Yes, Mozilla removed documentation for old SDK versions for some reason. I've updated the links to current version.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/using_postMessage

> As an alternative to port, content modules support the built-in message event. In most cases port is preferable to message events. However, the context-menu module does not support port, so to send messages from a content script to the add-on via a context menu object, you must use message events.